# AWS Lambda - import to cloudformation. Required properties

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

There is something that I don't understand in the concept of Cloudformation import feature.

I have a Lambda function, lets call it "myLambdaFunc".
"myLambdaFunc" is running and working.

Now I want to create a cloudFormation-stack to deploy the same Lambda.

So I followed [this article - "Bringing Existing Resources Into CloudFormation Management"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html).

My cloud formation file look like this:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Resources" : {
    "LambdaImportTest2" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::Lambda::Function",
        "DeletionPolicy" : "Delete",
        "Properties" : {
        }
    }
  }
}
```

But when trying to run the import in cloudFormation I get an "IMPORT_FAILED" error, because "Property Handler cannot be empty."

The error makes sense because the Property is empty.

But this is where my confusion starts - **I try to import an existing Lambda. I don't want to define a new Lambda.. So what should I put in the Property handler**? what code should I set there?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html

Comment: @AssaelAzran Thanks. I know this guide. But this is my problem: What do I put in the required property "Code"?  I expect it to be the code from the already running Lambda. Isn't it the meaning of importing existing resources to cloudformation?

Comment: You created your lambda in your aws console. it is not a resource inside an existing cloud-formation stack.

Comment: @AssaelAzran I'm not sure that you are right. according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html the import is from non-cloudformation resources into cloudformation.

Comment: i thought you created your lambda locally and you want to import it.

Comment: ok now i understand read this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-import-existing-resources-into-a-cloudformation-stack/  try to omit **properties** field

Comment: Thanks for this last link. But in that blog post the author imports S3 bucket and a Dynamo DB. Both of these resources are different from a Lambda function since the Lambda requires a property "Code". This "Code" property is the actual code to deploy in the Lambda.. But I want to import an existing Lambda

Comment: Did you try without properties field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202326/discussion-between-carmel-and-assael-azran).

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I think I figured out the confusion..

The main goal of the import process is to import the existing resource configuration.

In the case of a Lambda function - the main part of the resource is NOT the "Code" property. It can be copied manually from the existing Lambda.

When running the import I'll get the Lambda configuration in a cloudformation-stack, and I guess that is the main advantage in the import process, not needing to configure the resource by hand.